# Enter Text Based On Date

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a query that populates the next recertification date based on the last recertification date. What I would like to do is if the next recertification date is less than today, then "Past Due" is entered as a value in another field, but if it's greater than or equal to today, then "Certified".  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Status_Cert: IIf([PreviousRecert]+[RecertifyIndays]<=Date(),"Past Due",IIf([PreviousRecert] Is Null,"No Data","Current"))
```